# how does torrent streaming works using html5?

Tags: html, node.js, streaming, torrent

I stumbled upon [this site](http://joker.org/) and I wonder how does it work? I mean the streaming part

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is torrent streaming. I think it is regulat file streaming. And this file downloads with a torrent client on server side.
For example you can set uterrent (it supports downloading with first parts priority) to pickup new torrents from some folder. It start download automaticly. All you need is start stream this file for user when there is enough data downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

It's not html5 !

All videos are downloaded to servers using NodeJS Web technology.